# Cannot find role from command

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I have some roles in my discord server. Some is just for colors. I want to my members select the roles by their own with the command `.cargo <color>`

I have the code

```
if (command === 'cargo') {
    const colors = message.guild.roles.filter(role => role.name.startsWith('#'));
    if (colors.size < 1) return message.channel.send('Não há cargos nesse servidor');

    const str = args.join(' ');
    const role = colors.find(role => role.name.slice('#'.length).toLowerCase() === str.toLowerCase);

    if(!role) return message.channel.send('Esse cargo não existe!');

    try {
        await message.member.removeRoles(colors);
        await message.member.addRole(role);
        message.channel.send(`Agora você tem o cargo ${role}!`);
    }
    catch (e) {
        message.channel.send(`Falhei :( ${e.message}`);
    }
}
```

but everytime I type `.cargo` it's showing an error like the role doesn't exist `if(!role) return message.channel.send('Esse cargo não existe!');`

Errors that i noticed:

`.cargo` doesn't show the server roles and return the message that the role doesn't exist

`.cargo blue` return the message that the role doesn't exist

Comment: Have you tried logging the variables to see if they contain what you think they do? Also, what is the point of `'#'.length`? That's just `1`.

Comment: On the 5th line, you wrote `role.name.slice('#'.length).toLowerCase() === str.toLowerCase`, without the parenthesis. Is that a typo in your post or that's your code? If that's your code, it can't find the role because `String.toLowerCase` is a function, try calling it and see if that works

Comment: @FedericoGrandi it was not a typo ;-; so it worked

Comment: I'm getting missing permissions even tho the bot have it

Comment: I've added an answer so that you can accept it and close the question. For that other error, if you don't find anything on that error please open a new question, since it's not related to this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solution from the comments]
On the 5th line, you wrote `role.name.slice('#'.length).toLowerCase() === str.toLowerCase`, without the parenthesis. If that's your code, it can't find the role because `String.toLowerCase` is a function, try calling it and see if that works.